# Swift / UITableViewCell: Add disclosure indicator, when entering editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a custom UITableViewCell class and I want it to show a disclosure indicator, when entering edit mode.

This is my approach:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomCellClass = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass

    cell.counterTitle.text = "Cell Title"

    if self.tableView.editing {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    }
    return cell

}
```

I think I found an answer here, but I have difficulties with translating it into swift: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393026/redrawing-uitableviewcell-when-entering-exiting-edit-mode)

Do I need a 2nd custom cell class to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: what are you getting with the above code? any errors?

Comment: No errors, but the disclosure indicator doesn't show up either.

Comment: Try calling reloadData when you start editing your tableView - I can't remember off the top of my head if the delegate methods are fired automatically when the tableView enters editing mode. Aside from that, to further debug I would log out and make sure you are in fact in editing mode.

Comment: that one works, but without animation:     `self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true) self.tableView.reloadData()` It's not smooth at all like in the stock iOS clock app, when you press edit in the alarm list view.
I also thought of creating a 2nd custom cell class. Then I just need to tell UITableView to reload the data with the 2nd identifier. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, but in IB in the properties for the `UITableViewCell`, there's a dropdown for `Accessory` to set the accessory icon. Under that is `Editing Acc.` which also has all the standard accessories. If you set one there, it will only show up when editing and will properly animate in and out.

Comment: Also, programatically this can be set using `cell.editingAccessoryType = .disclosureIndicator`.